# Scanning a QR code into a browser text input?

Tags: qr-code

I have a bit of an edge use-case of QR codes. I would like to be able to scan a QR code via a phones camera and have that value pasted into a browser text input.

Is this possible given any current apps or API's?

Comment: I'd recommend you re-phrase your question (as it is phrased now, it's off topic on this site: we focus on end-users, development issues should go to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)). As you already can see, there are ways not involving development, as solutions already exist ;)

Comment: Any updates from your end?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Barcodescanner Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecit.android.barcodekbd.demo&hl=en).

> Soft-keyboard with integrated camera bar-code scanner lets you scan wherever you can type (free demo).
>   This soft-keyboard scans and enters barcodes directly into input fields of arbitrary apps, batch scanning mode is supported. It reduces manual typing and eliminates copy and paste. A special key invokes the built-in or an external camera barcode scanner. The setup wizard makes it easy to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Keyboard which has barcode scanning ability. Without a definitiv workflow requirement I would propose this: User visits website, goes to textfield X, actives barcode scanning in keyboard app, barcode is scanned and typed into targetfield.

Comment: While this might work: We are a user-oriented site. Development stuff should go to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) :)